# Does the code after the recursion call get executed only when the base case is reached?

Tags: python, recursion

I have written a recursion to reverse a linked list:

```
def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:

    #Base case
    if not head or not head.next:
        return head
    
    
    #Recurence relation
    second= head.next
    reverse = self.reverseList(second)
    second.next = head
    head.next = None
    
    return reverse
```

I have a simple question around the execution of the code, in particular for the recurrence relation.

The way I read it, the first two lines of the recurrence relation ensures that we move to and process the next node in the linked list.

However, my question is, when does

```
second.next = head
head.next = None
```

get executed? Is it only when the base case is reached? And in the meantime we store each of the partially complete calls in a recursion stack? Is this right?

Comment: You're exactly right. The code is executed line by line, and if one is a method, it may end before continuing

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Just wanted to make sure my logic is correct.

Comment: Azro, can I also ask- I am confused about the line "second.next = head" ; as we said this gets executed when the base case is reached, i.e. when head or head.next is None. But then won't second.next point to None? And so we are connecting our last node with None?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are curious how code is executed just insert some print statements.

```
def countDown(amount, depth = 0):
    if amount == 0:
        print("finished")
        return amount
    amount -= 1
    print("entering depth", depth + 1, "amount is", amount)
    amount = countDown(amount, depth + 1)
    print("exiting depth", depth, "amount is", amount)
    return amount

countDown(10)
```

output beautifully shows that function calls are put on stack and popped when early return happens

```py
entering depth 1 amount is 9
entering depth 2 amount is 8
entering depth 3 amount is 7
entering depth 4 amount is 6
entering depth 5 amount is 5
entering depth 6 amount is 4
entering depth 7 amount is 3
entering depth 8 amount is 2
entering depth 9 amount is 1
entering depth 10 amount is 0
finished
exiting depth 9 amount is 0
exiting depth 8 amount is 0
exiting depth 7 amount is 0
exiting depth 6 amount is 0
exiting depth 5 amount is 0
exiting depth 4 amount is 0
exiting depth 3 amount is 0
exiting depth 2 amount is 0
exiting depth 1 amount is 0
exiting depth 0 amount is 0
```

Comment: Thanks Jakub- this is super helpful